# wifi connection issue on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I was having a trouble with my wifi signal on ubuntu 16.04 .I sort that out but that only works temporarily and I have to face the same problem after reboot

Comment: "*trouble with my wifi signal*" is too vague to offer useful help, sorry. Your question should specify the trouble you are having, or the symptoms you are experiencing, and exactly what you do about it that works.

Comment: Please click [edit] and enhance your question by providing the nature of the problem. Also please run _sudo lshw|grep -A15 'network\|Wireless'_ and add that information to your question.